# Single noun meaning "having quality of artistic value/merit"

Tags: single-word-requests

Best word I could come up was "provocativeness", but I don't exactly like it. I don't think art has to be provocative. Well, the best art is probably provocative, but i.e. picture on a book cover whilst most often not provocative, still has more "artistic value" than some graffiti (which actually might be much more provoking) or a wall painted during renovation.

One word that sounded more pleasant is "artistry", but that seems to be a "quality of creator" rather than "quality of work of art".

Tags seem to ask me for a sample sentence, so here's one or two:

> My sister calls herself an artist, but * of her creations is rather poor.

> In general, cinematography has higher level of * than video games.

Comment: Apparently, 'inspirationality' hasn't made it into the lexicon yet. 'Inspirational' can mean either demonstrating or promoting ... er ... inspiration.

Comment: your 'quality' works nicely

Comment: [*Artistry*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artistry) also describes the object itself rather than the creator: " artistic quality of effect or workmanship // the *artistry* of his novel.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything better than the two word phrase "artistic value"

Answer (score 2):

One of the latent assumptions here is that artistic merit can be observed and compared. It sounds like a version of *high art* and *low art*, the former being for the upper crust or intellectual enjoyment and the latter being for the masses or for visceral response.

**Aesthetics** (noun) or **aesthetic** (noun or adjective) are often used to refer to the quality of appearance. I'll reproduce the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aesthetics) entry for the noun version:

> 1 *aesthetics also esthetics\ es-​ˈthe-​tiks
>   , is-​ , British usually  ēs-​\ plural in form but singular or plural in construction* : a branch of philosophy dealing with the nature of beauty, art, and taste and with the creation and appreciation of beauty
>
> 2 : a particular theory or conception of beauty or art : a particular taste for or approach to what is pleasing to the senses and especially sight
>
> > modernist aesthetics
> >
> > staging new ballets which reflected the aesthetic of the new nation— Mary Clarke & Clement Crisp
>
> 3 aesthetics also esthetics plural : a pleasing appearance or effect : beauty
>
> > appreciated the aesthetics of the gemstones

Definition 2 shows **aesthetic** used to classify specific works, as if each work has a *type* or *kind* of aesthetic. Meanwhile, definition 3 shows **aesthetics** to be used to evaluate the quality of appearance, whether it's the cut of a gemstone or the visual elements of a painting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest *expressiveness*, possibly with "artistic" if you need to emphasize that:

> My sister calls herself an artist, but the (artistic) expressiveness of her creations is rather poor.